# Starting application context without a main class

Tags: java, spring, jetty, quartz-scheduler

I am using a scheduler with Spring technology using Quartz.

Is it possible to launch my context without creating a main class? Not using the following example:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Quartz.xml");
    }
}
```

For example I want my Context to be configured when I launch my jetty server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch your spring application on an application server, you can use a listener inside of the web.xml to start your spring container.

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Another example:
If you want to use spring in a blueprint OSGi environment, the blueprint extender starts all contexts in META-INF/spring or OSGI-INF/blueprint for you.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I added the piece of code in my web.xml and the context is directly loaded at the launching of the server.